# Graven Image Question

Tags: kashrut-kosher, avodah-zarah, christianity

Can someone give me sources from Tanakh and Halakhah on why it is permissible for a Jewish [certified kosher] bakery to make images from Christianity and their winter holiday? And if it is permissible, can a observant Jew make those images in that bakery?

Comment: Regarding idolatry, only making or selling the *actual* idol that will be worshipped is forbidden to benefit from. Decorations that won't be worshipped are not forbidden to benefit from until they are designated for that purpose; at which point it is forbidden to sell to them.

Comment: I think we have a question similar to this regarding Jewish vendors in Rome selling Catholic symbols as souvenirs. @chachamNisan